Nautilus: End program after closing window
When I run nautilus from terminal it is still running after closing window.
I only get this message after start:
** Message: 00:10:10.307: Connecting to org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files

How can I set nautilus to end after closing the window ?
Thank you for help
PS: I am on walyand (sway) so I can not do some X based magic
